# django can't find the admin directory

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm new to learning django, and I get a 'template does not exist' error when trying to get to the admin site.

All the other answers have said

```
'django.contrib.admin',
```

wasn't in the

```
settings.py
```

file, but I've checked that and it is there.

I've also checked that the directory exists, it's in

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin
```

the directory of my app is

```
/media/sf_Python/mysite
```

which is in a virtualbox, but I don't know if that is the problem.

Without any entries in my url file, I am able to get the "It worked!" page, so some things are working.

Comment: Make sure you have app directories template loaders on... good luck!

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31952997/456550) suggests a full reinstall in to your virtualenv, using pip.

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --ignore-installed \
            --force-reinstall --upgrade --no-cache-dir
```

That worked for me, with Python 2.7.12, pip 9.0.1, and Django 1.4.

Comment: This solved my problem; just wanted to mention that it may save some time or hassle to run this for *only* django rather than your entire requirements.txt :)

Answer (score 0):

The second step of the docs. says:

> The admin has four dependencies - django.contrib.auth,
>   django.contrib.contenttypes, django.contrib.messages and
>   django.contrib.sessions. If these applications are not in your
>   INSTALLED_APPS list, add them.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/

Comment: Yes, all of those are in the settings.py. I only mentioned the 'django.contrib.admin' because the other questions I saw of people having the same problem displayed that missing app as the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Check the settings.py and then don't forget to run `python manage.py syncdb`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:                                                                                                                          
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:                                                                                                                
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

Then, you have to edit the urls.py (it is in the same place as settings.py. Uncomment all the lines that say "uncomment to enable admin". It is a couple of imports and one regular expression.
Then run your server.
This link may help: http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter06.html